# Error on script linked to getlastrow - i think

Tags: google-apps-script

I can see that this has been asked elsewhere however the solutions have not worked for me or I have not understood them.

I have been using this bit of code for some time in multiple google sheets without issue. Suddenly this one sheet is throwing up the error "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

Can anyone help me resolve?

The code I have is as follows:

```
function submit() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Check Sheet");
   var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
   sheet1.getRange("A1:AA1").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stzckoverflow, can you add the solutions found in other questions that did not work for you ? (and/or maybe a link to those questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are getting this error because the last row with content in sheet `Data` (that is, `sheet2.getLastRow()`) is also the last row of the sheet, regardless of content. That is, you are trying to copy a range to a row (`sheet2.getLastRow() + 1`) that does not exist.

To avoid this error, you should insert a new blank row before copying the range if the last row with content is the absolute last row of the sheet. You can use [getMaxRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) to check that.

So you could add this just before using `copyTo`, to insert a row if the last row with content is the absolute last row in the sheet:

```js
if (sheet2.getLastRow() === sheet2.getMaxRows()) {
  sheet2.insertRowAfter(sheet2.getLastRow());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)
- [Sheet.insertRowAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition)